# Syntax error at a semicolon in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

The one liner command will be longer but this is the part that is throwing the error.

```
for user in natural1 ; do 
cat <<EOT >> /home/$user/public_html/.htaccess
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/$user/.htaccesspasswd"
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
EOT
; done

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Comment: remove `;` in `; done`. bash is not C. bash is cranky if you add unnecessary ; where you already have newline

Comment: Simple, I was under the impression that is required always when closing the for statement, thanks much!

Comment: Actually bash treats `;` as a linebreak. So your can either use a semicolon between natural1 and do, or put do on the next line. Both would be valid syntax. A lot of programmers use the semicolon because they find it neater to contain the loop declaration to a single line. Because of this it never makes sense to start a line with `;` in bash that I can think of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A semicolon or ampersand (`;` or `&`) in a shell script is a command terminator. You can't use it if it doesn't follow a command. `;` means “run the preceding command in the foreground” and `&` means “run the preceding command in the background”.

A newline in a shell script is a “weak” command terminator. If there is a command to terminate, it's equivalent to a semicolon. If there is no command to terminate, the newline has no effect.

The newline after `cat <<EOT >> /home/$user/public_html/.htaccess` terminates the `cat …` command. So the semicolon after the here-document has nothing to terminate. (A here-document is not a command; the here-document is attached to the command on the preceding line, i.e. the `cat …` command.) If you wanted to explicitly terminate the `cat …` command with a semicolon, you'd need to put it at the end of the `cat …` line.

Comment: Your answer has been correct in 2015, but it is no longer 100% correct today. A command line beginning with a semicolon is no longer an error.

Comment: @schily On the machine I'm using right now, dash, bash, lksh, mksh, posh and Busybox sh all complain about a leading `;`. Only ksh93 and zsh are happy with it. My answer applies to systems that people are likely to encounter, not what the latest POSIX draft says.

Comment: `ksh93` does it since a longer time and I implemented it in `bosh` a year ago after we decided to change the POSIX syntax last year. I wanted to explain that there is a tendency to permit it even though this change still does not permit e.g. `{ ;`.